# Tuning sequential disk reads for performance

Tags: linux, performance, disk

I am reading a large file sequentially from the disk and trying to understand the `iostat` output while the reading is taking place.

- Size of the file : 10 GB
- Read Buffer : 4 KB
- Read ahead (/sys/block/sda/queue/read_ahead_kb) : 128 KB

The `iostat` output is as follows

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00  833.00   14.00   103.88     0.05   251.30     6.07    5.69    2.33 205.71  1.18 100.00
```

Computing the average size of an I/O request = (rMB/s divided by r/s) gives ~ 128 KB which is then the read-ahead value. This seems to indicate that while the read system call has specified a 4KB buffer, the actual disk I/O is happening according to the read-ahead value.

When I increased the read-ahead value to 256KB, the `iostat` output was as follows

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    28.00  412.00   12.00   102.50     0.05   495.32    10.78   12.15    4.76  265.83   2.36 100.00
```

Again the average I/O request size was 256 KB matching the read ahead.

This kept up until I set 512 KB as the read-ahead value and did not hold up when I moved up to a read-ahead value of 1024 KB - the average size of the I/O request was still 512 KB. Increasing max_sectors_kb (maximum amount of data per I/O request) from the default of 512 KB to 1024 KB also did not help here.

Why is this happening - ideally I would like to minimize my read IOPS as much as possible and read a larger amount of data per I/O request (larger than 512 KB per request). Additionally, I am hitting 100% disk utilization in all cases - I would want to throttle myself to read at 50-60% disk utilization with good sequential throughput. In short, what are the optimized application/kernel settings for sequential read I/O?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely being limited by the `max_sectors_kb` setting for `/dev/sda`.

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/max_sectors_kb
```

almost certainly returns 512.

You should be able to change it to 1024 with something like:

```
echo 1024 > /sys/block/sda/queue/max_sectors_kb
```

Assuming you don't run into another limit, that should up the IO size you see to 1024 KB.